# Entity Framework 6 + SQLSpatialFunctions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, geospatial, entity-framework-6

I'm in the process of migrating a code base from the Entity Framework 5 to 6. I've found documentation to assist in this but I'm finding some challenges with the changes made to DBGeography and specifically SQLSpatialFunctions. EF6 contains breaking changes that include removing classes out of System.Spatial over to System.Data.Entity.Spatial (and into the core EF assembly and out of System.Data.Entity). I have not found a replacement for the SQLSpatialFunctions in the EF6 and due to the breaking changes I can't make use of the existing ones. I know these are essentially queries against functions in SQL Server but they were very convenient, they integrate into my queries nicely, and I rather not have to develop my own library to accomplish this (I started to investigate EdmFunctions but it seemed to be a bit of a rabbit hole).

Anyone with any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the EntityFramework.SqlServer assembly (where they belong), in the System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace, see https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/879

Comment: Thanks - this was easier than looking through the MSDN docu.